# deserialize xml to c# object

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

i have the following xml (which i can not edit):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<ns0:prices xmlns:ns0="http://schemas.some.com/sadas/Output">
  <pricepoint>
    <esid>
      ENG.GPL.DAY_AHEAD.PROMPT.PH.M
    </esid>
    <observationdate>20120123</observationdate>
    <observationtime>0000</observationtime>
    <price>22.1250</price>
    <quote>Q</quote>
  </pricepoint>
  <pricepoint>
    <esid>
      ENG.NBP.DAY_AHEAD.PROMPT.PH.M
    </esid>
    <observationdate>20120123</observationdate>
    <observationtime>0000</observationtime>
    <price>53.8500</price>
    <quote>Q</quote>
  </pricepoint>
  <pricepoint>
    <esid>
      ENG.NCG.DAY_AHEAD.PROMPT.PH.M
    </esid>
    <observationdate>20120123</observationdate>
    <observationtime>0000</observationtime>
    <price>22.0750</price>
    <quote>Q</quote>
  </pricepoint>
  <pricepoint>
    <esid>
      ENG.TTF.DAY_AHEAD.PROMPT.PH.M
    </esid>
    <observationdate>20120123</observationdate>
    <observationtime>0000</observationtime>
    <price>21.9500</price>
    <quote>Q</quote>
  </pricepoint>
  <pricepoint>
    <esid>
      ENG.ZEEBRUGGE.DAY_AHEAD.PROMPT.PH.M
    </esid>
    <observationdate>20120123</observationdate>
    <observationtime>0000</observationtime>
    <price>53.6500</price>
    <quote>Q</quote>
  </pricepoint>
</ns0:prices>
```

and the following object i want to map it to:

```
[Serializable]
public class Prices 
{

    public List<Pricepoint> prices { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
public class Pricepoint
{

    public string Esid { get; set; }

    public DateTime Observationdate { get; set; }

    public int Observationtime { get; set; }

    public double Price { get; set; }

    public string Quote { get; set; }

}
```

Using the following method:

```
    public static object Deserialize(Type typeToDeserialize,byte[] bytes)
    {
        var mem = new MemoryStream(bytes);
        var ser = new XmlSerializer(typeToDeserialize);
        return ser.Deserialize(mem);
    }
```

which is invoed by `Deserialize(typeof(Prices), byteArrayofXMLfile);`

I do however get an error regarding the namespace line of the xml:

```
There is an error in XML document (3, 2)
```

I cant figure out what i am doing wrong here?

Comment: You should use the Data Contract Serializer for serializing Data Contracts.

Comment: never mind the datacontracts, they are not supposed to be there, will edit :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

resolved the problem by letting visual studio generating the classes for me:

```
C:\>xsd latest.xml
Microsoft (R) Xml Schemas/DataTypes support utility
[Microsoft (R) .NET Framework, Version 4.0.30319.1]
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
Writing file 'C:\latest.xsd'.

C:\>xsd latest.xsd /classes
Microsoft (R) Xml Schemas/DataTypes support utility
[Microsoft (R) .NET Framework, Version 4.0.30319.1]
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
Writing file 'C:\latest.cs'.
```

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT**:
Just re-read and saw you were asking about the namespace.  Use the `Namespace` property of `XmlRootAttribute` as shown below.

---

You'll need  to tell the XmlSerializer what tags map to what properties through attributes:

```
[Serializable]
[XmlRoot(Namespace = "http://www.ZomboCorp.com/", ElementName="prices")]
public class Prices 
{
    [XmlElement("pricepoint")]
    public List<Pricepoint> prices { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
public class Pricepoint
{

    [XmlElement("esid")]
    public string Esid { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("observationdate")]
    public DateTime Observationdate { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("observationtime")]
    public int Observationtime { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("price")]
    public double Price { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("quote")]
    public string Quote { get; set; }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
XmlRootAttribute r = new XmlRootAttribute("prices");
r.Namespace = "http://schemas.some.com/sadas/Output";

var ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Prices),r);
return ser.Deserialize(mem);
```

PS: you should also consider casing of tag names